# Setuptools does not use ~/.pip/pip.conf global.index-url

Tags: python, pip, setuptools

I have a local pip mirror so I have this particular pip config in my home directory:

```
[global]
index=file:///somewhere/python/pypi_mirror/simple
```

When I do `pip install module` the dependencies are correctly fetched from the local mirror.

However, when I install a package using the command line:

```
python setup.py install
```

Python tries to fetch the dependencies from pip.org, not from my local mirror.

Why?

Notice the issue also appear with `PIP_INDEX_URL`:

```
export PIP_INDES_URL=http://you_failure
python setup.py install
...
Searching for xmltodict
Reading https://pypi.python.org/simple/xmltodict/
...
```

Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Python setup install is calling your setup.py directly https://docs.python.org/2/install/ . No pip included. If you want to use pip to install the local package do a `pip install -e .` or if you don't want to use the global pip config, but only the index for this very package put it inside a requirements.txt with the content:

```
--index-url file:///somewhere/python/pypi_mirror/simple

-e .
```

I highly recommend https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/user_guide/

Comment: You didn't understand the question. OP is asking about the dependencies. These *are* installed using pip.